# SGS3 LTE (GT-i9305T) Set preferred network type

Tags: settings

Looking for a way to perform the function equivalent to: `*#*#4636#*#*` --> 'Phone Information' --> 'Set preferred network type'

Because above code is not working on my both phones SGS3 LTE (GT-i9305 and GT-i9305T)

The article [Change WCDMA to GSM automatically](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28553/16575) is for SGS2 and it doesn't work for SGS3.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Exactly what are you asking?

Comment: I am a mobile field technician needs to change my mobile settings from 3G to 2G to LTE to do test call

Comment: What phone are you trying to do this on?

Comment: Both Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE (GT-i9305 and GT-i9305T)