# How to turn off cellular radio in Lollipop/JellyBean using adb?

Tags: adb, cellular-radio

I've been trying to find out how to kill/turn-off cellular radio (on a rooted device) using some command on ADB. My research only found that I should either (using GUI) enable **Airplane Mode**, or type some [code](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28557/96277) to go to **Phone Information** and then tap **Turn radio off**.

But that's not how I want to do it.

- I'm looking for a single or a set of commands to do the job here. (**Note** that I'm aware of using **am start** and **input tap** combination, but that's same as emulating the GUI.)
- Also, in my OnePlus One (CM12), **Airplane Mode** as it seems only hides the Cellular icon. As soon as I disable the mode the signal reappears instantly, while signal takes bit longer when **Turn radio (off -> on)** is used?

  Any good reason for this?

Thank you! Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

From [DavisNT answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15877584/2821954),

> There exist a simple workaround on **rooted** devices.
>
> To enable Airplane Mode the following root shell commands can be used:
>
> ```
> settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
> am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true
> ```
>
> To disable Airplane Mode these root shell commands can be used:
>
> ```
> settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
> am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state false
> ```

Comment: I just tested it on Nexus 5 running Lollipop and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me the trouble. I was halfway through though with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319129/how-to-change-preferred-network-type-over-adb-android/26416538#26416538), but it required reboot. Your technique doesn't require reboot which is great. Thanks again!