# Enable On-screen navigation in CM12 (Lollipop) using shell?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, command-line, navigation-bar, softkey

Device: OnePlus One (OPO); running CM12, is rooted, and has Xposed Framework installed.

---

I need to enable **On-screen navigation** (it disables Hardware (HW) keys and shows soft keys at the screen; like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCNdP.png)) in OPO. I'm able to do it via **Settings** but my objective requires a command-line solution through shell.

<sub>(Note that this is not a development/programming question, simply an Android question.)</sub>

- **Objective**: To disable Back(HW) key  when main activity of an app (random) is in foreground, but without a reboot.
- I found On-screen nav. to be a good choice which doesn't require a reboot. I'll use an automation app to trigger the disabling action.
- There are manual ways to disable HW keys (by editing `.kl` files) and enabling Soft keys (by editing `build.prop`), or using tools like Xposed modules to disable or swap HW keys. **But they all require reboot (soft/hard) at least once** which I cannot afford.
- I experimented  and found that when On-screen nav. is enabled, the value for `dev_force_show_navbar` changes to `1` from `0`. Similarly. `button_brightness` changes to `0` from `255`. Both names are under `Settings.db` (Table:`secure`)
- Also, there is no special activity assigned for **Settings → Buttons**(it enables On-screen nav). I used `dumpsys activity | grep mFocusedActivity` to see activity related to **Buttons**. The result was:

  ```
  com.android.settings/.SubSettings
  ```
- `dumpsys activity activities` or `dumpsys activity recents` also has nothing more to tell here.
- I logged my actions using `logcat` when enabling On-screen nav. and [here](http://www46.zippyshare.com/v/03ctwJXK/file.html) is the log file.

So, **how do I enable On-screen nav. through command line, irrespective of whether it requires superuser access or not?**

**Edit**: Is there any *other* way using which I can achieve the objective precisely?

---

<sub>Only thing that comes to my mind is to use  `input  <keyevent>` but that's counterproductive to me. The other way is to trigger an Xposed module like **Xposed Additions** but I'm unable to use it with shell.</sub>

Comment: I know you can enable it within the build.prop just add this at the end: `qemu.hw.mainkeys=0`

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Thanks for explicitly mentioning it, but as I already mentioned about it in the question, *it needs reboot to take effect* which I cannot afford.

Comment: sorry didn't notice that, maybe you can decompile `settings` and take a look how they did it then.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab [Here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/cm-12.0/src/com/android/settings/ButtonSettings.java) is the source. Can you help how can it  be used in a shell?

Comment: I took a look at the code, there is a way to disable the hardware buttons, and enable the navigation buttons, but it is coded and can't be used in the commanline. Where are you going to execute that shell command? You can maybe launch an activity of an app I/we can make that automatically does it in the background. (In java code) @Firelord

Comment: @SuperThomasLab I already straightened out launching or relaunching an activity of an app by using Tasker and shell commands, but I'm stuck at the final objective (see my edit).

Comment: Then can't you just make a simple app that enables/disables the navigationbar?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab If only I was a developer I could have solved the issue. :)

Comment: I could give it a try... Although i'm just a beginner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25183/discussion-between-firelord-and-superthomaslab).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I experimented and found that when On-screen nav. is enabled, the value for `dev_force_show_navbar` changes to `1` from `0`... Both names are under `Settings.db` (Table:`secure`).

You actually mentioned the key to the answer but somehow (I suppose) didn't know how to use it. Many thanks to [Andrew T.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/44325/andrew-t) and [DavisNT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927592/davisnt) for [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111513/109933) since it would lead to a solution for your problem.

I myself is a owner of OnePlus One running stock CM12 so you may now expect a working answer.

From the shell, be it `adb`, or a [Terminal app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=terminal&c=apps), or [Tasker's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) "Run Shell" action, enter the following command with root privileges:

```
settings put secure dev_force_show_navbar 1
```

You would now see that On-screen navigation bar is enabled just like in your pic posted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCNdP.png).

Don't worry about `button_brightness` since the changes in its value would be reflected automatically by the above command.

I tested that command in Tasker by manual execution of action "Code -> Run Shell -> *command*" with "Use Root", and its working good.

The changes are exactly same as doing it from "Settings -> Buttons" so nothing to worry, i.e. **only Soft-keys are visible and Hard keys are disabled**. Coolest part -- **no reboot needed.**

You can revert back by using `0` in place of `1` in the aforesaid command.

Comment: Does this only work on CyanogenMod, or also on stock ROMs?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab I so far tried on CM12 (Cyanogen OS 12, stock ROM for OnePlus One) only. It is dependent on `settings.db`. If the Stock ROM differs in features then the solution may not work.

Comment: I would like the readers to note that in some other custom ROMs the table  `system` has that key value so the command would be `settings put system dev_force_show_navbar 1`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a solution for your question. All the ways to do it will require a reboot except the `Settings` app for Cyanogenmod. I took a look at the [source code of Cyanogenmod](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/cm-12.0/src/com/android/settings/ButtonSettings.java) how they managed to get it working, and I found this:

This is the method that does enable/disable the navigationbar:

<sup>(Sorry if this is off-topic, wanted to add this in case others are interested)</sup>

```
private static void writeDisableNavkeysOption(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    final int defaultBrightness = context.getResources().getInteger(
            com.android.internal.R.integer.config_buttonBrightnessSettingDefault);

    Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEV_FORCE_SHOW_NAVBAR, enabled ? 1 : 0);
    CmHardwareManager cmHardwareManager = (CmHardwareManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CMHW_SERVICE);
    cmHardwareManager.set(CmHardwareManager.FEATURE_KEY_DISABLE, enabled);

    /* Save/restore button timeouts to disable them in softkey mode */
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    if (enabled) {
        int currentBrightness = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.BUTTON_BRIGHTNESS, defaultBrightness);
        if (!prefs.contains("pre_navbar_button_backlight")) {
            editor.putInt("pre_navbar_button_backlight", currentBrightness);
        }
        Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.BUTTON_BRIGHTNESS, 0);
    } else {
        int oldBright = prefs.getInt("pre_navbar_button_backlight", -1);
        if (oldBright != -1) {
            Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.BUTTON_BRIGHTNESS, oldBright);
            editor.remove("pre_navbar_button_backlight");
        }
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

As you can see it uses `android.hardware.CmHardwareManager` and the stuff is hard coded into the ROM and it's not possible to make it yourself.

**Edit:** There is a solution for the question. Look at the accepted answer. I already had it in my answer:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEV_FORCE_SHOW_NAVBAR, enabled ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: Hi `SuperThomasLab`, [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/113413/96277) seems to suffice what I intended to know. We both thought the goal might not be possible to achieve but it can be done. Have a look at it. :)

Comment: @Firelord you had it in your answer, and I had it in my answer... Why didn't we see it :)

Answer (score -2):

What I can suggest is - Install [Gravity Box](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox) and enable the Navigation Bar from there.

Comment: How does Gravitybox helps especially when the developer mentioned that it's not meant for CM like ROMs?

Comment: Gravitybox is working fine on my CM12.1 based ROM.

Comment: GravityBox is an Xposed Module and the device still needs to be  restarted at least once. Besides, how do I use it using shell?

Comment: Can you soft reboot the phone and use the method by SuperThomasLab above?

Comment: I cannot afford any kind of reboot.