# How to remove soft navigation keys in Xperia without affecting Dialer's call button?

Tags: custom-roms, sony-xperia, softkey

I am using Micromax A310 running a custom rom (Sony Xperia).

Whenever I try to remove the soft navigation keys by editing *build.prop*, the soft nav keys are removed successfully, but my dialler's call key also disappears. The only option remain is to switch to some third party dialler, which I don't prefer.

Please provide some pointers on how to remove the soft nav keys without affecting the stock dialler's call button.

Comment: Which Android version and custom ROM are you using? See if [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/113413/96277) is applicable (change `1` to `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the soft keys using Gravity Box, a module for the Xposed framework. Gravity box will let you tweak parts of Android without the need for a custom ROM. There are 3 different versions of Gravity Box for 3 different versions of Android (JB, KK and LP). Link for framework: [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer). Link to modules: [Modules](http://repo.xposed.info/module-overview). You can then search for the module you want.

Comment: Good that you took care of first thing, but would you please (as asked earlier) mention the usage specific to the relevant goal. I use this module and it has humongous options, so do explain the usage.

Comment: Well, the OP wants to hide soft keys. I'm just suggesting him to do that using GravityBox.The usage is obvious here. What else should I specify?

Comment: An analogy, if you wanna browse an FTP server, you don't just say use "ES file Explorer", you mention: Download, install and launch it -> open server tab -> list XYZ details -> check this or not -> and it will do the job. You guide the person since the app isn't dedicated to the job. As I said, the suggested app has many option, so you gotta tell **how** to disable/remove soft keys using it.

Comment: Well, its been a long time since I asked this, but just want to notify that using GravityBox is not working. Any other method please?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide navigation keys and at the same time save your dialer by installing a [Xposed module - Noverflow](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.el1t.noverflow). After that edit the build properties and restart your phone Twice.