# Enable/disable navbar NO REBOOT

Tags: tasker, navigation-bar

I am using Linage 16 and there I have got enable navbar setting. I want to enable navbar using Tasker program. I have read some info here: [Enable On-screen navigation in CM12 (Lollipop) using shell?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112283/enable-on-screen-navigation-in-cm12-lollipop-using-shell/113413) . But I still don't understand how to make it.

Comment: I need to enable/disable navbar using shell, java etc. Editing build.prop is not suitable for me

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! It would help if you could [edit] your question and include where you are stuck. What is it you didn't understand? Have you Tasker installed, and established task and condition? Does it not work? Did you try it from the command line, e.g. via `adb shell "settings put secure dev_force_show_navbar 1"`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, it doesn't work. There is another method in the link I have given,  but I don't understand what to do

Comment: If it doesn't work from `adb shell` it's unlikely the same command works from Tasker (if you referred to something other, please be more specific). What I *could* imagine (being with Android since v2.x) is that the Google devs again thought that's something a normal user should'nt be able to. Is your device rooted? Then you could try the same command after having executed `su` for super-user powers.

Comment: My device is roote., I have tried  command from shell(I have typed command "su" before) and tasker, nothing is working

Comment: How can I use this line: Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEV_FORCE_SHOW_NAVBAR, enabled ? 1 : 0);

Comment: Only from code (so you'd need to write an app for it).

Comment: There is "java function" task in Tasker. Maybe it can be used?

Comment: Try it and tell us – I've never used that.

Comment: I don't know how to use it. I am noob in java

Comment: So am I, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting haven't tested this thoroughly but you can try this;

> Tasker now has `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission to the Manifest.
>   Hence it is now easier to control device Secure/Global settings
>   without needing an additional plug-in such as AutoTools or SecureTask.

You can enable this new permission by issuing the following command via ADB (**important**):

```
adb shell pm grant net.dinglisch.android.taskerm android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Now the business end you, since you want to use the Java function proceed as follows:

We need to call,

```
cr = CONTEXT.getContentResolver();
Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
Settings.Secure.DEV_FORCE_SHOW_NAVBAR, 1);)
```

As usual create a task to this this, name it accordingly.

The following actions are found under Code → Java function

A1: Java Function [ **Return**:`cr` **Class Or Object**:`CONTEXT` **Function**:`getContentResolver {ContentResolver} ()`

A2: Java Function [  **Class Or Object**:`Secure` **Function**:`putInt{boolean} (ContentResolver, String, int`) **Param(ContentResolver)**: `cr` **Param**(string):`dev_force_show_navbar` **Param**:(int):`1`

Save and execute task to test

---

However I would have preferred a simpler route with run shell (Tasker) or adb:

A1: Code Run shell [Command: `settings put secure dev_force_show_navbar 1` Tick **Use root**]

or

```
adb shell settings put secure dev_force_show_navbar 1
```