# How do I enable Airplane mode using Tasker on Android 4.2.2?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, tasker, airplane-mode

How do I enable airplane mode automatically at 01:00 AM using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) on Android 4.2.2?

The Airplane mode setting inside Tasker under **Action -> Net -> Airplane mode** cannot be activated:

> Airplane mode is not available in Android 4.2+, try the Secure Settings plugin and a rooted device.

My device is rooted. How do I properly use the [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) plugin to enable Airplane mode automatically at the said time?

Comment: Have you already installed *Secure Settings?* What have you tried to activate Airplane Mode? According to the graphs in my [Tasker Graphs](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker#group_950) section, you should be able to use it via *Plugin­ › Secure Settings*, finding it there under *Actions › Airplane Mode*.

Comment: @Izzy Seems that the plugin has shifted the option after the last time you checked its latest version, and the new location is **System+ Actions -> Airplane Mode**. :)

Comment: @Firelord makes sense, given that it now requires root. You know: each new Android version since 2.2 brought a new restriction. This one was AFAIR introduced with 4.2. So it looks like I need to update that graph. As you've just played with *SecureSettings:* did you spot any other deviation I should consider? E.g. "Airplane Mode Radios", did it move as well? // Ouch, PS: Position of menu items seems to depend on Android version. On my device with 4.1.2, *Airplane Mode* is still listed in "Actions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notes:**

- The answer is tested on a rooted Android 4.2.1 running Tasker  v4.6u3m and Secure Settings v1.3.6.
- Secure Settings may needs to be installed as a System app (it has the provision under `SYSTEM+` in its GUI).

---

Since you're already aware of making profiles, tasks, and actions, I would come to point:

1. Make a profile having time as the context, and create a new task in it.
2. Under that Task, the action would be **Plugin → Secure Settings → Configuration** (pencil icon) →  **System+ Actions → Airplane Mode → On → Save** (floppy icon), and save your action under the task.

Now whenever the time would come Tasker would execute Airplane mode, and everyone would be happy!

You can automatically disable the Airplane Mode as well, by choosing `Off` or `Toggle` over `On` in the aforesaid step.

---

For Readers: If you don't happen to have Secure Settings or it's not working somehow, then you can use the following action as an alternative. ([Credits to Andrew T. and DavisNT for their answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111513/96277))

Action: **Code → Run Shell**, and enter these details:

- **Command**: `settings put global airplane_mode_on 1; am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE --ez state true`
- Check **Use Root**

That would execute the Airplane mode based on your profile.

To automatically disable the said mode, create an another action in a different profile and copy the aforesaid action with exception of `0` over `1` and `false` over `true`.

You're good to go now!

Comment: Oh, did I mention that the alternative can actually be used on a non-rooted phone as well (hint: ADB running wirelessly, and  use `adb connect `in loopback), perhaps not on 4.2 but 4.4 and 5.0 can do the job.