# How can I force version 5.0.1 on Note 4 to only connect to 4G LTE when available?

Tags: data-connection, samsung-galaxy-note-4, 4g

My Note 4 running 5.0.1 will often connect to 4G rather than 4G LTE when both are available.  When this happens I can turn airplane mode on and off it will then reconnect to 4G LTE, sometimes with 5 bars.

How can I either make it:

- Only connect to 4G LTE
- Never connect to 4G
- Only connect to 4G LTE when both are available
- Strongly prefer the 4g LTE connection over the 4G even when LTE has less bars

One or any combination of the above points would be great. I have an unlimited data plan and I think AT&T likes to slow me down because of it. Any ideas?

Comment: See this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28557/109933). You'll see some network modes. Choose the one suitable to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Firelord, I think this may have worked - I selected LTE Only as preferred network type - will let you guys if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, the best I knew was to  see available network modes in that "Phone Information". Could you post screenshots of available network modes there? I need to see something.

Comment: I did it wrong the first time *facepalm* I think this worked now...

Comment: Congrats then! Could you post it as an answer so that others may benefit from it in future?

Comment: OK so the answer is the following: 

In dialer, press *#*#4636#*#*
Go to 'Device Information'
Scroll down to this 'Set preferred network type'
Click the dropdown
You have the option of "LTE only"

***IMPORTANT NOTE***
This disabled my incoming calls and they were going straight to voicemail. Not sure if this is a NYC thing or if voice just generally never goes over LTE but i had to switch it back.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28557/109933) (by [Void](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/18638/void)) worked well for OP. You can setup your device to connect to "4G LTE" only by using the following steps:

1. In dialer, press `*#*#4636#*#*`
2. Go to **Phone Information**
3. Scroll down to **Set preferred network type:** and tap the entry below it.
4. Choose **LTE only**.
5. Optionally: Tap **Turn off radio** → **Turn on radio**

Or,

If you cannot access that menu using the code in dialer, then install and launch [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir&hl=en) → **information**
→ tap **Telephony** → **Turn WiMAX (4G) on** → repeat aforesaid **steps 3-5**.

#### An important note by OP

> This disabled my incoming calls and they were going straight to voicemail. Not sure if this is a [New York City (high volume - stressed network)] thing or if voice just generally never goes over LTE but [I] had to switch it back.

Comment: You may choose any other network type as well if your needs differ from OP.

Comment: Worked fine to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Force 4G LTE Switch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mmmdevelopers.forcenetwork) app.

It allows to force 4G/3G/2G and also provides "network operators" search shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the app "4g lte only switch- speed test" app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplistic.forcelte

Comment: Can you add some more detail? The system thinks this is spam due to its low quality and link, but It seems legitimate **provided you give more info**