# Moto G2 internet connection switch from 3G to 2G network

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, mobile-network, 3g

I am using Moto G2 with Lollipop 5.0.2. And I am having this trouble that whenever I am using 3G service, it automatically switches to 2G and in between it gets back to 3G. This keeps on going and internet speed suffer. Please help if anyone has any clue.

Comment: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28557/96277) is what you need to look and follow. Reverse the condition in step 4.

Answer (score 2):

The default setting provided in the Phone settings menus is

```
Setting > More > Mobile Networks > Preferred network type > 3G
```

[image: Pref_network_Screenshot]

<sub>Screenshot - Preferred Network Type selection(Click to enlarge image)</sub>

This is a WCDMA(3G) preferred setting and that means it switches to 2G network if you have a weak 3G signal recepition in your area.

**For enabling `3G only` mode follow these steps:**

Firstly we need to define in which SIM we want to enable 3G. For this go to-

Settings > Dual SIM settings > Mobile Data > choose the desired SIM.

Now,

- Open your Phone (Dialler) app.
- Enter this code: `*#*#4636#*#*`
- An app known as "Testing" will be launched.
- Touch the first option "Phone information". (Don't touch other options)
- You will notice a drop-down option above "turn off Radio" button. Tap on it.
- Select the third option "WCDMA Only".

You will see that network has changed to 3G mode in the notification bar. If network doesn't change, touch the "Turn off Radio" button. you will see your phone's signal are lost. Now again turn it on by tapping on the same button. Your `3G/HSPA/UMTS` must have been enabled now.

[image: Screenshot_wcdma_only_mode]

***Note***: If you set `WCDMA only` mode and if your 3G network is weak, then it will not switch back to 2G network as a fallback and you will eventually lose your connection until you get back the 3G network. So you might face some interruptions while downloading/streaming etc. Instead of entering the code in the phone dialer you can use this tiny app from playstore called [Testing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=diewland.testing.phone)

**How to switch back to default?**

Select ‘WCDMA preferred’ from the above dropdown list and you will go to 2G/3G mode where your phone will connect to best network mode depending on strength.